# Is it possible to save browser tab, including javascript variables, content of form fields, cookies, etc. for offline viewing later?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser, javascript, snapshot

I'm trying to save a state of card in browser (preferably firefox or chrome). Is it possible? Something like snapshot in VirtualBox.

Let's say I'm using javascript app that doesn't have save feature and doesn't connect to web after starting. I want to save state of it.

Comment: This has been asked on our sister site: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3079329/how-to-save-a-tabs-memory-state-in-firefox-chrome Based on the lack of answers there, I'm guessing the answer is No. Browsers aren't designed to do this, and there doesn't appear to yet be an extension that offers that function either.

Comment: web is stateless. the site must be specially written to achieve anything like this.